# How do I test out my parser grammar in ANTLR4?

Tags: parsing, token, antlr, antlr4, lexer

I wrote a parser grammar in ANTLR4 which looks like this:

```
parser grammar IFJ23;

tokens {
    Identifier, Type,
    LeftBracket, RightBracket,
    LeftCurlyBracket, RightCurlyBracket,
    Semicolon, Colon, Arrow, Comma,

    /** Keywords */
    FunctionKeyword
}

swiftFile
    : functionDeclaration swiftFile
    ;



/** Statements */
statement
    : declaration Semicolon?
    ;

statements
    : statement statements?
    ;

codeBlock
    : LeftCurlyBracket statements? RightCurlyBracket
    ;



/** Declarations */
declaration
    : functionDeclaration
//    | variableDeclaration
    ;



/** Function declarations */
functionDeclaration
    : FunctionKeyword Identifier functionSignature functionBody
    ;

functionSignature
    : parameterClause functionResult?
    ;

functionBody
    : codeBlock
    ;

parameterClause
    : LeftBracket RightBracket
    | LeftBracket parameterList RightBracket
    ;

functionResult
    : Arrow Type
    ;

parameterList
    : parameter
    | parameter Comma parameterList
    ;

parameter
    : externalParameterName? localParameterName typeAnnotation
    ;

externalParameterName
    : Identifier
    ;

localParameterName
    : Identifier
    ;

typeAnnotation
    : Colon Type
    ;
```

Now, the problem I am facing is that I already have a functional lexer that is not written in ANTLR4. It's written in C and it generates a list of tokens for a file.

Is there a way to somehow make ANTLR4 accept this token list as input and try to generate a parse tree?

I would also need to match the tokens in the `Tokens {}` list with their respective token types generated from my lexer.

Comment: From the 2 grammars, a lexer grammar is by far easier to implement. I am pretty sure that rewriting the lexer grammar in ANTLR would be less work than trying to make the other lexer to cooperate with the ANTLR parser.

Comment: @BartKiers thanks for the response. I guess you've convinced me... The problem is, we only have a diagram of the finite automaton that's being used. Is there some recommended approach to converting this automaton into a set of rules for the ANTLR lexer?

Comment: (1) As far as specifically the testing scenario mentioned, there is nothing in the Antlr toolkit that can use a different lexer or reads a list of tokens as input and wraps them in a token stream. But, you could do this easily by writing a specialize token stream that calls your lexer instead of https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/487cb28bd359587e67794b25b144b7df83ddf1a2/runtime/CSharp/src/BufferedTokenStream.cs#L240.

Comment: (2) Going from an NFA to regular expression [is easy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6SyRwpyQF6I), but taking that to an Antlr lexer grammar with separate lexer rules for each token would not be easy. That is because Antlr lexer rules follow (a) longest match first, then (b) first rule matches. Unless you are intimately familiar with that, I would just write a one-rule lexer grammar.

Comment: @kaby76 thanks for the comments. So essentially what you're proposing is first converting my NFA to a regular expression and then writing a lexer rule that contains this regular expression? My problem here is that depending on where (on which final state) my NFA stops, it outputs a different token type (e.g. `WhileKeyword`, `Identifier`, `Double`...). And I am using these token types in my parser. Would creating a single lexer rule be able to produce all these different token types that are specified in the `tokens` declaration in my `.g4` file?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean. Each alt in the rule would have a different `-> type(...)`. If your lexer has different entry points for a parser or if it looks at parser state of any kind then you will need to figure out an alternative implementation using Antlr lexer rules and modes, because Antlr does not pass parser state to the lexer. All this assumes you want a rigorous translation of an NFA to Antlr lexer rules. You may be able to just come up with the rules off the top of you head instead, or from a spec if you have one. But of course nobody writes specs anymore.

Comment: @kaby76 thankfully there is just one entry point with multiple finishing states, each producing a token of some sort. Could you please point me to some documentation? Because I'm very new to ANTLR and I don't quite understand what you mean by `-> type(...)`.

Comment: See https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md#lexer-commands